# Assigning from a Class method binds the class instead of its return value

Tags: ios, objective-c, return-value, class-method, toll-free-bridging

I've noticed something strange in the behavior of code I'm currently writing and thought I would ask here to see if I'm doing something silly that would cause this to happen.

Basically, when I assign a variable to the return value of my class method, instead of the variable holding a reference to the return value, it's holding a reference to the class. See the code below:

```
NSArray * newAddresses = [MyHost addressesForHostname: @"google.com"];
```

Which has a method signature of

```
+ (NSArray *) addressesForHostname: (NSString *)hostname
```

And returns

```
return (__bridge_transfer NSArray *) ipAddresses; // ipAddresses is a CFMutableArrayRef
```

As you can see, I'm using toll-free bridging to use CoreFoundation objects as I'm collecting a list of IP addresses for some network interfaces.

After `newAddresses` has been assigned to, I look at the class of the `newAddresses` array in LLDB and get:

> (lldb) po [newAddresses class]
>   MyHost

Am I mistaken in my assumptions about how I'm using `__bridge_transfer`? All of the objects use to make up `ipAddresses` are `CFStringRefs`.

**EDIT**: I was asked for the whole method, so here it is!

```
+ (NSArray *) addressesForHostname: (NSString *)hostname {

    CFMutableArrayRef ipAddresses;

    DLog(@"Getting addresses for host name %@", hostname);

    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)(hostname));
    CFStreamError error;

    BOOL didResolve = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, &error); // synchronously get the host.

    if (didResolve) {

        CFArrayRef responseObjects = CFHostGetAddressing(hostRef, NULL);
        long numberOfResponses = CFArrayGetCount(responseObjects);
        ipAddresses = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, numberOfResponses, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < numberOfResponses; ++i ) {

            char * ipAddress;
            CFDataRef responseObject = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(responseObjects, i);
            struct sockaddr * currentAddress = (struct sockaddr *) CFDataGetBytePtr(responseObject); // Unwrap the CFData wrapper aound the sockaddr struct

            switch (currentAddress->sa_family) {

                case AF_INET: { // Internetworking AKA IPV4

                    DLog(@"Extracting IPV4 address");
                    struct sockaddr_in * socketAddress = (struct sockaddr_in *) currentAddress;

                    ipAddress = malloc(sizeof(INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET,
                              &(socketAddress->sin_addr),
                              ipAddress,
                              INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

                    CFStringRef ipAddressString = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, ipAddress, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
                    CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex(ipAddresses, i, ipAddressString);

                    free(ipAddress);
                    break;

                }

                case AF_INET6: { // IPV6

                    DLog(@"Extracting IPV6 address");
                    struct sockaddr_in6 * socketAddress = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) currentAddress;

                    ipAddress = malloc(sizeof(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN));
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6,
                              &(socketAddress->sin6_addr),
                              ipAddress,
                              INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

                    CFStringRef ipAddressString = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, ipAddress, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
                    CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex(ipAddresses, i, ipAddressString);

                    free(ipAddress);
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    DLog(@"Unsupported addressing protocol encountered. Gracefully ignoring and continuing.");
                    break;
            }


        }

        CFRelease(responseObjects);

    }

    CFRelease(hostRef);

    return (__bridge_transfer NSArray *) ipAddresses;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `ipAddresses` within the method or better yet, post that whole method? It looks like it's not actually an array (CFMutableArrayRef). Perhaps it's being accidentally reassigned somewhere.

Comment: Good idea Ben. I went ahead and did that. You'll see that I don't reassign to `ipAddresses` after I create it - I just mutate it using `CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex`. When I look at the array on the return line in `addressesForHostname`, it appears correct. This leads me to believe that the `__bridge_transfer` is the culprit, but I'm not too experienced with toll-free-bridging.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution, and it lies in me forgetting to initialize `ipAddresses = nil` before anything happens. The way this code is written, it won't assign a value to `ipAddresses` if it's unable to resolve the `hostRef` given to `CFHostStartInfoResolution`. With no value in `ipAddresses`, it returns an uninitialized pointer that gets casted and has its ownership transferred.

I can't find formal documentation that states this, but I believe this would be undefined behavior.

I should state that if anyone is using this code as reference, I'm experiencing inconsistent crashes on the line where I release `hostRef`. This is unrelated to the issue that I created for this thread, but is worthwhile to point out.